# Multi Line Button in codename one

Tags: lwuit, codenameone

I have to display a text line as a button. 
The text of line is more then limit of line so when i display it in button it scroll the text rather then display multi line button.

Please help to make it multi line.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use MultiButton but you will have to do linebreaks yourself.

Alternatively you can use a TextArea which supports multi line and if you don't need the pressed state you can just set it to editable false and use `setUIID("Button")` to make it look like a button. If you need something more elaborate you can use the lead component approach to build a button from a text area, to understand how that works look at the source code for multi button and read the documentation for setting the lead component in the Container class.

Comment: Hi Sir, Thanks. Solved with custom button.

Answer (score 0):

You can't do multi lines because button extands from label in lwuit. In this case you can use in ticker mode.