# how to insert break line for long text on button in codenameone using gui builder

Tags: codenameone

I want to insert break line for long text on button same like wrapping text.

So help me in that. How can I break long text and set it on button in `codename` one using `Gui builder`?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Multi Line Button in codename one](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15358489/multi-line-button-in-codename-one)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use the [SpanButton](https://www.codenameone.com/javadoc/com/codename1/components/SpanButton.html) class, I think it's exposed in the GUI builder.